# codeigniter mongodb performance

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

When i am running my mongodb query in shell, i get results set in few milliseconds. and when i execute this same query in codeigniter i get results in 12 seconds.

Shell script

```
db.order.find({customer_email:/^asd@asd.com/}).explain()
```

Codeigniter script

```
$orderData = $this->mongo_db->get_where('order', array('customer_email'=> new MongoRegex("/^asd@asd.com/i")));
```

Is there any solution to optimize speed of fetching results?
There are 7272699 total records and i need to find asd@asd.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should set an index on customer_email if not already. Second, try to remove the i flag in the MongoRegex to use the index:

```
$orderData = $this->mongo_db->get_where('order', array('customer_email'=> new MongoRegex("/^asd@asd.com/")));
```

Comment: Hi Steyx, after removing i flag it improved performance but i need to search data in case insensitive.

Comment: Then the query can't use the index. Another solution would be to always lowercase customer_email before writing it to mongo.